# Module build failed: Error: Cannot find module './globals.json' Create-React -App

Tags: webpack, create-react-app

I have a Create-react-app application I have been working on for a month.

I am now getting an error when building or running:

```
npm run start
```

> Starting the development server... Failed to compile.
>
> ./src/index.js Module build failed: Error: Cannot find module
>   './globals.json'

now the issue is I dont even know where to look. It gives me no indication of which module has the problem. Is there a way to turn on verbose for some more debugging information?

Any guidance would be appreciated.

My package.json:

```
{
  "name": "hbi.contractor",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "homepage": "http://www.mysitecom.au/app",
  "proxy": {
    "/api/*": {
      "target": "https://api.mysite.com.au",
      "changeOrigin": true
    }
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome": "^1.1.8",
    "axios": "^0.17.1",
    "immutability-helper": "^2.7.0",
    "inputmask": "^3.3.11",
    "jquery": "^3.3.1",
    "materialize-css": "^0.100.2",
    "nodemon": "^1.17.4",
    "react": "^16.3.2",
    "react-dom": "^16.3.2",
    "react-dropzone": "^4.2.9",
    "react-format-number": "^1.3.1",
    "react-html-parser": "^2.0.2",
    "react-ionicons": "^2.1.6",
    "react-live-clock": "^2.0.3",
    "react-load-script": "0.0.6",
    "react-maskedinput": "^4.0.1",
    "react-moment": "^0.7.0",
    "react-owl-carousel": "^2.2.0",
    "react-redirect": "^1.0.0",
    "react-redux": "^5.0.7",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.2.2",
    "react-rxinput": "^1.0.4",
    "react-scripts": "1.0.17",
    "react-sticky": "^6.0.2",
    "react-sticky-el": "^1.0.17",
    "react-text-mask": "^5.4.1",
    "redux": "^3.7.2",
    "redux-form": "^6.8.0",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.2.0",
    "universal-cookie": "^2.1.2"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "react-input-mask": "^1.2.2",
    "react-materialize": "^1.1.2",
    "react-native-masked-text": "^1.6.5",
    "react-number-format": "^3.3.4"
  }
}
```

my index.js (entry point)

```
import "jquery/dist/jquery.min.js";
import "materialize-css/dist/js/materialize.js";
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from "redux";
import reduxThunk from "redux-thunk";
import App from "./components/App";
import reducers from "./reducers";
import "./index.css";
import queryString from "./utilities/querystring";
import "materialize-css/dist/css/materialize.min.css";

const electionId = queryString.getParameterByName("electionId");
const store = createStore(reducers, {election: electionId}, applyMiddleware(reduxThunk));

if (electionId){
ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <App />
  </Provider>,
  document.querySelector("#root")
);
}
else{
  ReactDOM.render(
    <div>
      Missing Vote Id
    </div>,
    document.querySelector("#root")
  );

}
```

Comment: I think it most likely has something to do with updating Node or NPM..

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this by deleting the node_modules folder and then running npm install again